# I need this for license check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

is there a way to get from SQL Server a unique identifier?

**I need this for license check**. My application uses SQL Server and I give an activation key that is generated using that **unique number**. This means that the activation key will enable the user to launch the application only if he is connecting to the server he paid the license for.

It would be better and easier for me to directly call some SQL Query to retrieve some unique number that is generated once SQL Server is installed.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`NEWID()` function will give you a GUID if that will work for you. If not you could write a function to generate a random number, store it in a table with a unique index, and return it if the insertion into the table is valid.